# Is there a better way to find an specific object inside an array by name?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I know this could be easily done with a loop like I'm doing in the method below. I'm just wondering if there is any pre-build function that I can use to get the same result my code gets here:

```
const openExerciseListModal = (index:number) =>{
let selectedValue = selectedItems[index];
items.forEach((element,index) => {
  if(element.value===selectedValue){
    alert(index)
  }
});
savedExercises = [...selectedExercise]
setExerciseListModalVisible(() => !isExerciseListModalVisible)
```

My array is something like this:

```
[{ label: "Monday", value: "Monday" },{ label: "Tuesday", value: "Tuesday" }]
```

My goal is to click the button in my screen and get the index of that item in my array. If the user press on Monday, it gets 0 for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably go with something like:

```
const index = items.map(({ value }) => value).indexOf(selectedValue)
```

Map over the items to create an array of the exact thing you are searching for, and then find the index of that thing.

---

Note: for very large arrays, this may be slow since it's actually looping over the results twice. But for something like days of the week, it's going to be fine.